custom font can't apply in xib
I've followed Apple's directions to add custom font in Xcode 15.3, like root folder/Fonts/, and add Fonts provided by the application in plist, but I cannot apply when in XIB's UILabel, UIButton, etc.
I tried to add a blank value for the Application fonts resource path. Sometimes I can choose the custom font, but sometimes it disappears. Does anyone have any solid solution on how to add and put these TTF files? I think it's an old issue since Xcode 15 but no one fixes it.


Could someone tell me how to place font files and apply them to XIB?

Are you setting fonts using XIB or programmatically ?
